# Can a unitary matrix be reducible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given an $n\times n$ unitary matrix $U$, is it possible for $U$ to be reducible? That is, can $U$ be transformed via a permutation transform $P$ such that the transformed matrix $PUP^{-1}$ is in upper block diagonal form?

Answer (score 2):

If a matrix is block triangular and nonsingular, the diagonal blocks are invertible and 
$$\pmatrix{A & B \\ 0 & C}^{-1}=\pmatrix{A^{-1} & -A^{-1}BC^{-1}\\ 0 & C^{-1}}.$$

Assume that $U$ is unitary and reducible. Since for any permutation matrix $P$, $PUP^T$ is unitary as well, we can assume that $U$ is already in the block triangular form:
$$U=\pmatrix{U_{11}&U_{12}\\0&U_{22}}.$$
Hence
$$\tag{1}
U^{-1}=\pmatrix{U_{11}^{-1}&-U_{11}^{-1}U_{12}U_{22}^{-1}\\0&U_{22}^{-1}}.
$$
However, since $U$ is unitary,
$$\tag{2}
U^{-1}=U^*=\pmatrix{U_{11}^*&0\\U_{12}^*&U_{22}^*}.
$$
Now (1) and (2) imply that $U_{11}$ and $U_{22}$ are unitary and $U_{12}=0$. Hence a reducible unitary matrix is block diagonal with unitary diagonal blocks. A trivial example of a reducible unitary matrix is the identity.

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer has been very helpful indeed :)